# How can i display the firebase error message from terminal to UI?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have been trying to show this alert message in column within safearea. I have to show this message as error message, where initially errormessage is string with null value. The error message appears successfully in terminal but not getting on screen.

```
 try {
```

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

```
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  _auth
      .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: username + '@mail.com', password: password)
      .then((log) {

    var key = prefs.setString('key', username);
    Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (BuildContext context) => Mails()),
        (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
  });
} catch (e) {
  showDialog(context: context, builder: (context) => Dialog(child: Text(e.toString()),));
  
  print('This is what we got ${e.message}');
}
```

here is my debug console

```
E/flutter ( 3195): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(157)] 
Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND, There 
is no user record corresponding to this identifier. The user may 
have been deleted., null)
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #0      
StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #1      
MethodChannel.invokeMethod[39;49m
E/flutter ( 3195): <asynchronous suspension>
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #2       
MethodChannel.invokeMapMethod[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 3195): #3      
FirebaseAuth.signInWithCredential[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 3195): #4      
FirebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword[39;49m
[38;5;248mE/flutter ( 3195): #5      _LoginState.loginuser[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #6      _asyncThenWrapperHelper.
```

(dart:async-
patch/async_patch.dart:73:64)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #7      _rootRunUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1134:38)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #8      _CustomZone.runUnary  (dart:async/zone.dart:1031:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #9      _FutureListener.handleValue  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:139:18)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #10     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:680:45)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #11     Future._propagateToListeners  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:709:32)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #12     Future._addListener.  (dart:async/future_impl.dart:389:9)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #13     _rootRun  (dart:async/zone.dart:1126:13)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #14     _CustomZone.run  (dart:async/zone.dart:1023:19)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #15     _CustomZone.runGuarded  (dart:async/zone.dart:925:7)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #16     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.  (dart:async/zone.dart:965:23)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #17     _microtaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:43:21)[39;49m
[38;5;244mE/flutter ( 3195): #18     _startMicrotaskLoop  (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:52:5)[39;49m
E/flutter ( 3195):

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
catch(e){
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Dialog(child: Container(..<What you want to show>...)); );
}
```

you dont need setState

Comment: I tried this but didn't work at all. Error comes in terminal but doesn't reflect in UI as dialog. Thanks for your time though

Comment: can you show the error?, also its did you try ```e.toString()```

Comment: Yes I tried .toString() but didn't work. I even tried to print a dummy message in catch block that didn't even got printed. I don't know what's happening. Here is the code and debug console.

Comment: I have posted codes above and debug consoles. Have a look please. It doesn't even print the print statement. even the error is throwing.

Comment: When a user updates their email, password or resets their password. Firebase Auth backend revokes their tokens requiring that they reauthenticate or try to sign in again. This is a security feature. For example a user may reset their password if their account was compromised. All other sessions must reauthenticate.This is happening because the email with you are login/sign-in with does not exist, either you have to register that email it with auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword then login/sign-up or correct your email and password.

Comment: You didn't understand. I know the problem but I am creating it cause I want that error on screen when people login with email that doen't exist. I am doing it purposefully to get that error on screen like when someone types wrong password it should display WRONG PASSWORD. That is what i want. I want error to be thrown at ui and not only in terminal when i build a release bundle.

Comment: I already have created a signUp function and i have access to database too. I just want this error on screen when someone mistakenly types wrong data in those fields.